# ConfigObj and absolute paths

Tags: python, path, configobj

i'm having a bit of a path issue when using configobj for python. i'm wondering if there's a way to not use an absolute path in my helper file. For example, instead of:

```
self.config = ConfigObj('/home/thisuser/project/common/config.cfg')
```

i want to use something like:

```
self.config = ConfigObj(smartpath+'/project/common/config.cfg')
```

**Background:**
i've placed my config file in a common directory along side a helper class and a utility class:

```
common/config.cfg
common/helper.py
common/utility.py
```

the helper class has a method that returns the values within the section of the config. the code is as such:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

class myHelper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigObj('/home/thisuser/project/common/config.cfg')

    def send_minion(self, race, weapon):
        minion = self.config[race][weapon]
        return minion
```

the utility file imports the helper file and the utility file is called by a bunch of different classes stationed in different folders of my project:

```
from common import myHelper

class myUtility:

    def __init__(self):
        self.minion = myHelper.myHelper()

    def attack_with_minion(self, race, weapon)
        my_minion = self.minion.send_minion(race, weapon)
        #... some common code used by all
        my_minion.login()
```

the following files import the utility file and calls the method:

```
/home/thisuser/project/folder1/forestCastle.py
/home/thisuser/project/folder2/secondLevel/sandCastle.py
/home/thisuser/project/folder3/somewhere/waterCastle.py

self.common.attack_with_minion("ogre", "club")
```

if i don't use an absolute path and i run forestCastle.py it looks for the config in **/home/thisuser/project/folder1/** and i want it to look for it in **project/common/** because **/home/thisuser** will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate a new absolute path based on a module filename instead:

```
import os.path
from configobj import ConfigObj

BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


class myHelper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigObj(os.path.join(BASE, 'config.cfg'))
```

`__file__` is the filename of the *current* module, so for `helper.py` that would be `/home/thisuser/project/common/helper.py`; `os.path.abspath()` makes sure it is a absolute path, and `os.path.dirname` removes the `/helper.py` filename to leave you with an absolute path to the 'current' directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of a hard time following what you actually want.  However, to expand the path to your home directory in an OS-agnostic fashion, you can use `os.path.expanduser`:

```
self.config = ConfigObj(os.path.expanduser('~/project/common/config.cfg'))
```